# Switching Users in word requires a restart

Tags: microsoft-word

I've got multiple users logged into Microsoft Word, a company account and a personal account. Lately, every time I switch between Microsoft accounts, Word prompts me to restart *all* of the Microsoft products on my computer. This is extremely annoying, because it's *every time I switch users*, which is quite frequently.

More specifically, it tells me that my new privacy settings have been applied and to restart Office for them to take effect.

Is there some magic setting I can change so it either doesn't change privacy settings or so it doesn't prompt me to restart Office?

My company account has an O365 account, but my personal account does not

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What policies is your business account applying to Word on your computer? Have you asked them if they have applied policies that may affect this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go to one Office app, such as Word > File > Account > Connected Services, please check whether your personal Microsoft account was listed there.

If so, please removed it.

If you can not remove any Connected Services, please close all Office apps, go to Registry Edirtor, delete the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity` hive.

And then resign your accounts into Office apps to have a check.